# Pretty new to Linux - Not able to print with HP LaserJet 1102W

Tags: printing

I invested in a Dell Inspiron 1525N with Ubuntu 8.04 factory installed.  I never did much with Ubuntu because XP was working fine.  Recently, I upgraded the Inspiron 1525 to Ubuntu 14.04. It has been very sluggish compared to a Windows 7 that I am now using on an Acer Aspire 4730Z.  I have never got a printer to run on any of my Linux systems.  I am using a HP Laserjet 1102W. I've tried the Install/Remove software menus with no success.  This printer model was not listed in the Linux drivers.

Has anyone had any luck with an HP LaserJet 1102W on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Sorry for posting this type of question in the wrong forum.  I'm just becoming acquainted with Linux OS's and the associated communities.

Comment: Run `hp-setup` in a terminal and follow the steps for getting set up. I don't have an HP printer so I can't test it myself but that should either fix it or get you well on the way to fixing it. Useful links: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102.html and http://hplipopensource.com/node/309